# Mistake in the Proof for Fundamental lemma of calculus of variation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

In this [link](https://mecheng.iisc.ac.in/suresh/me256/notes3_2007.pdf), the second fundamental lemma of calculus of variation (Lemma 2 in the link):

*If $\alpha(x)$ is continuous in $[a, b]$, and if*
$$
\int_a^b \alpha(x) h^{\prime}(x) d x=0
$$
*for every function $h(x) \in \mathscr{D}_1(a, b)$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$, then $\alpha(x)=c$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$, where $c$ is a constant.*

... is proved by constructing $h(x)$ and $c$ for a given $\alpha(x)$ function, and claims that this proves the lemma.

This doesn't make sense, since the lemma claims that the above holds for **every** function that is continuous & continuously differentiable within [a,b] satisfying the boundary constraints, not just a specifically constructed h(x).

Am I misunderstanding the proof?

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding the proof. Given $\alpha$ satisfying the assumptions, you may choose any $h$ you like that satisfies the assumptions
if it helps you to prove that $\alpha$ is constant.

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm not sure I understand (also sorry for the notation, replace $/alpha$ with F for the proof in the link) - iiuc the proof works by constructing a *specific* h for a given F(x), namely the definite integral of F.